# Add news email to mailjet by the REST API

Tags: java, mailjet

I making one application that can send different email, but the email address depends of the user. I'm using mailjet to do this, after reading the doc, it's seem that i have to add every email for have the right to send email from this address, but this address are not generate by me (they are gmail, toto, etc)

I already use the Java API of mailjet to add user, and this part is working fine

But my problem is when the validation email arrive, and the person follow the link, mailjet ask to login, but he do not know what to do, because normally is my own account, i only what to add their email address to have the right to send email with them.

So the question, is how i can add email address (from gmail, yahoo...) and activate the user, without the login part.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for having choosen Mailjet to power your email!

I believe the right setup for you would be to use the `Sender` header. It will allow you to send email from a unique (or multiple, depending of your setup) pre-validated sender email addresses while setting the `From` email header to the email you want to send the email from.

In your recipients Inbox, it will display as `foobar@gmail.com via notifications@mycompany.com`, indicating clearly to the recipient that you're sending on behalf of `foobar@gmail.com`. This way, you won't be forced to validate each email address, just ones you'll

This is a very common setup for resellers and platforms sending a lot of personalised email.

In order to achieve this, please contact our [support team](https://app.mailjet.com/support] with a reference to our discussion here so they know what we're talking about. They'll guide you to the implementation it.

Hope it helps,
Best.